# проблема с циклом в excel или запись в csv файл (Python)

Tags: python, csv

У меня такая проблема, уже около 3х часов думаю как реализовать код.
1)Есть цикл, который записывает в файл csv.
2)Есть переменные, которые берутся из парсера.
Но при записи в csv файл, переменные накладываются друг на друга.
Данный код лежит в цикле:

```
application_number = a
application_title = b

my_dict = [[str(application_number), str(application_title)],
                   ]
        with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=' ')
            writer.writerows(zip(*my_dict))
```

переменные "a" и "b" вырезал из парсера, чтобы удобнее было найти решение, там разные значения каждый 
 шаг цикла.
нужно решение, как сделать, чтобы при следующем шаге цикла переменные записывались справа от старой записи, а не перезаписывали их.

сейчас они выглядят вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

следующий цикл его перезапишет,
а должны так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может открывать файл не на запись, а на добавление?

Comment: боже.. я сидел 3 часа.. а оказалось дело в одной букве..
Спасибо большое!
А как вывести, чтобы добавление было в соседней строке, а не ниже?

Comment: Так вы же записываете в *csv*, все новые данные идут на новой строчке. Вы ходите изменять структуру файла каждый раз, это неправильно

Comment: Понял..
А если реализовать, чтобы вывод переменных был горизонтальным?

Comment: Вы можете использовать *pandas* и создавать из ваших данных любой датафрейма какой хотите и при полном его заполнении уже сохранять в *csv*

Comment: Да, спасибо за совет, однако, у меня 60000+ шагов цикла..

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответы, нашел решение)